# Cleanup function which puts age in age group bucket - possible?

Tags: php, code-cleanup

I have this function which categorizes the age of a user in a certain age group:

```
private function calculateAgeGroup($age)
{
    if (!$age) {
        return null;
    }

    if ($age <= 25) {
        return '0-25';
    }

    if ($age <= 30) {
        return '26-30';
    }

    if ($age <= 35) {
        return '31-35';
    }

    if ($age <= 40) {
        return '36-40';
    }

    if ($age <= 45) {
        return '41-45';
    }

    if ($age <= 50) {
        return '46-50';
    }

    if ($age <= 60) {
        return '51-60';
    }

    return '61-';
}
```

Is there a way to simplify (meaning: less verbose, less if statements) this? My first thought was about using modulo, but I dismissed that very fast as it just doesn't make sense to use modulo here.

Second option would be something like `floor($age/10)*10 . "-" . ceil($age/10)*10` but that also doesn't work in all cases.

The last option which came to my mind would be using a series of `() ? :` statements which would make for shorter but NOT more readable code. Also not so good.

Anyone has any good idea how to simplify this? Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `switch` may help you in this case..nested `if elseif` too

Comment: @swapnesh how so? As far as I can tell php can only evaluate on the exact value, not on something like `case $age <= 50:`.

Comment: @Max, php can http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php#88643. However in you case it won't make your code much smaller/cleaner

Comment: @claarman true, doesn't make the code much shorter, but learned something new, thank you!

Comment: @Max Sorry for the late response..as claarman said it is not the case, I added both in my answer.check accordingly(although i tested it before)..let me know if something went wrong with the understanding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function calculateAgeGroup($age) {
    switch($age) {
    case $age <= 25:
        return '0-25';
        break;
    case $age > 50 && $age <= 60:
        return '51-60';
        break;
    case $age > 60:
        return '61-';
        break;
    default:
        return (floor(($age-1)/5)*5+1) . "-" . ceil($age/5)*5;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but should be `((floor(($age-1)/5)*5)+1)` to give desired output. and special case `51-60` is not covered.

Answer (score 4):

As a base you can use the following code for your increments:

```
private function calculateAgeGroup($age)
{
    if (!$age) return null;
    for ($i=25; $i<=60; $i+=5) {
        if ($age <= $i) return ($i-4 > 25 ? $i-4 : 0) . '-' . $i;
    }
    return '61-';
}
```

Comment: Change `i` to `$i` :) +1 for the logical way of implementation :)

Comment: my bad, to much javascript lately ;)

Answer (score 2):

This should exactly give the desired output..so modulus was not a bad idea:

```
function calculateAgeGroup($age)
{
    if (!$age) { return null; }
    if ($age <= 25) { return '0-25'; }
    else if ($age > 50 && $age <= 60) { return '51-60'; }
    else if ($age > 60) { return '61-'; }
    $age = (($age%5) != 0) ? ($age - ($age%5) + 1) : ($age -= 4);
    return $age.'-'.($age+4);
}
```

Another option, where the values are precomputed:

```
function calculateAgeGroup($age)
{
    $age = ($age <= 25) ? 0 : ($age-1) - (($age-1) % 5);
    $age = ($age >= 60) ? 60 : $age;
    $ages = array (
        0 => '0-25', 25 => '26-30', 30 => '31-35',
        35 => '36-40', 40 => '41-45', 45 => '46-50',
        50 => '51-60', 55 => '51-60', 60 => '61-',
    );
    return $ages[$age];
}
```

I benchmarked the solutions and the first solution with modulus is the fastests from all provided answers since there is not much calculation involved.

It would be even faster if you take the array out of the function and make it global or as (static) class property.

```
$ages = array (
    0 => '0-25', 25 => '26-30', 30 => '31-35',
    35 => '36-40', 40 => '41-45', 45 => '46-50',
    50 => '51-60', 55 => '51-60', 60 => '61-',
);

function calculateAgeGroup($age)
{
    $age = ($age <= 25) ? 0 : ($age-1) - (($age-1) % 5);
    $age = ($age >= 60) ? 60 : $age;
    global $ages;
    return $ages[$age];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can minimize your code using `switch` case or nested `if elseif` statement.

Using `switch case`:

```
function calculateAgeGroup($age)
{
    switch($age){
        case $age <= 25:
        return '0-25';
        break;

        case $age > 60:
        return '61-';
        break;

        default:
        if( $age/5 == 0 )
        $age = $age - 1;

        return (floor($age/5)*5).' - '.(ceil($age/5)*5);
        break;
    }
}
```

Using nested `if elseif` statement:

```
function calculateAgeGroup($age)
{
    if($age <= 25)
    return '0-25';
    elseif($age > 60)
    return '61-';
    else
    {
        if( $age/5 == 0 )
        $age = $age - 1;

        return (floor($age/5)*5).' - '.(ceil($age/5)*5);
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
function calculateAgeGroup($age)
{
    if($age <= 25)
    return '0-25';
    elseif($age > 60)
    return '61-';
    else
    {
        return ($age%5 == 0)?(floor(($age-1)/5)*5).'-'.(ceil(($age-1)/5)*5) : (floor($age/5)*5).'-'.(ceil($age/5)*5);
    }
}
```

I tested the code and both code more or less taking same time to execute.

Testing code-

```
$time_start = microtime(true); 
for($i=24;$i<62;$i++)
{
echo "Age $i :";
echo 'Age Group :'.calculateAgeGroup($i);
echo '<br>';
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;

//execution time of the script
echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins';
```